# php domdocument createelement method automatically changing special characters

Tags: php, createelement

I'm creating an XML according to a user input. suppose the user entered one of the XML special characters, i want to replace it to it's XML representation.
Now, suppose:

```
$value = 'bla"bla';
```

And this is my code:

```
$value = str_replace(array("&", "<", ">", "\"", "'"), array("&amp;", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&quot;", "&apos;"), $value);
//at this point the value of $value is 'bla&quot;bla'
$attrRoot = $doc->createElement($key, $value);
//at this point the value of $attrRoot->nodeValue is 'bla"bla' again.
```

I want the value to appear inside my XML like the value of $value.
any suggestions?

Comment: why dont you use `htmlentities()` instead of that str_replace ? http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: and what is the output that you are getting?

Comment: [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) is going to be safer in XML than `htmlentities`.  With hte, you need to worry about including the entity definitions.  With hsc, you don't, but you run the risk of encoding hilarity.